# HTML inline forms with buttons

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="text-right">
    <form method="post" action="create_car_type.html">
        <button type="submit" value=4 class="btn btn-danger ml-2 mr-3" title="Create a car type">
            Create a type
        </button>
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="delete_car_type.html">
        <button type="submit" value=3 class="btn btn-warning ml-2 mr-3">
            Delete a type
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

These two buttons are inside forms, which are inside a div. They are right aligned in this div, but I would like to display them inline. The way they are displayed currently is that one places above the other, which is something I want to avoid. Should I include something like `display: inline` somewhere? Where should this go?

Answer (score 1):

add style="display: inline-block;" to form tags

```
<div class="text-right">
    <form method="post" action="create_car_type.html" style="display: inline-block;">
        <button type="submit" value=4 class="btn btn-danger ml-2 mr-3" title="Create a car type">
            Create a type
        </button>
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="delete_car_type.html" style="display: inline-block;">
        <button type="submit" value=3 class="btn btn-warning ml-2 mr-3">
            Delete a type
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a **`display: flex` or display: inline-flex** to your main div tag and this is the most easy way to make something inline. something like this

```css
.text-right{
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px; /*also you can use gap to give a space between them*/
}
```

```html
             <div class="text-right">
                <form method="post" action="create_car_type.html">
                    <button type="submit" value=4 class="btn btn-danger ml-2 mr-3" title="Create a car type">
                        Create a type
                    </button>
                </form>
                <form method="post" action="delete_car_type.html">
                    <button type="submit" value=3 class="btn btn-warning ml-2 mr-3">
                        Delete a type
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
```